# Как изменить цвет поисковой строки в мобильном Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

Мне надо сделать цветной панель поиска в Google Chrome, например, как у лайфхакера:

[image: скриншот лайфхакера.]

Пробовал сделать это с помощью

```
<meta name="theme-color" content="#цвет">
```

Но увидел всю ту же белую панель.

---

Помогла чистка кэша

[image: Скриншот получившейся панели.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У лайфхакера в коде стоит: `<meta name="theme-color" content="#eb5e42">`
Может Вы не туда тег вставили? Это нужно между `<head></head>` добавить.
Так же, возможно, Вам нужно почистить кэш браузера в телефоне.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/181687)

Comment: @br3t, вполне содержится.

Comment: Спасибо, чистка кэша помогла.